# PyQt5 installation failure

Tags: 14.04, python-2.7, pyqt5

I want to install PyQt5. I followed the instructions. Everything has been ok (`python configure.py` and `make`) until I run this command:

```
sudo make install
```

Where I got this error message:

```
cd QtCore/ && ( test -e Makefile || /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/qmake /root/Bureau/PyQt-gpl-5.4.1/QtCore/QtCore.pro -o Makefile ) && make -f Makefile install
make[1]: Entering directory `/root/Bureau/PyQt-gpl-5.4.1/QtCore'
install -m 644 -p /root/Bureau/PyQt-gpl-5.4.1/QtCore/QtCore.so /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyQt5/
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/share/sip’: Not a directory
make[1]: *** [install_sip] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/Bureau/PyQt-gpl-5.4.1/QtCore'
make: *** [sub-QtCore-install_subtargets-ordered] Error 2
```

How to fix this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install the **[SIP](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/sip/download)** wrapper before you install PyQt5.

Alternatively, the package `python3-pyqt5` is in the repos.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Do you mean if I install `python3-pyqt5` I won't encounter this problem ? (In fact, I installed SIP last week but I had so many troubles to install PyQt5 since that)

Comment: Yes, installing a package via `apt-get` or the Software Centre will automatically install all of its dependencies.